# Error on delete file after consume - activemq

Tags: blob, activemq-classic

I am getting error when delete file after consume blob message in activemq. Here is my error stack trace.

Note - Downloaded successfully. Getting error on delete -

```
activeMQMessage.deleteFile();
```

Error:

```
entejavax.jms.JMSException: Delete file failed: 550 Delete operation failed.

at org.apache.activemq.blob.FTPBlobDownloadStrategy.deleteFile(FTPBlobDownloadStrategy.java:66)
at com.skynetwork.sync.FileSyncListener.onMessage(FileSyncListener.java:66)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1298)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:122)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:43)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be ftp server problem, can you verify if you can delete it with FileZilla or other FTP tool and if name on the consumer side contains blanks or special caracters. Did you have FTP side logs.

Comment: It was url problem. I fixed it and it works. Thanks for your response.